# Is explicitly calling constructors and destructors safe, according to the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, constructor, standards, destructor

Some developers call constructors and destructors explicitly for some workarounds. I know, it is not a good practice, but it seems it is done to realize some scenarios.

For example, in this article, [Beautiful Native Libraries](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/8/18/beautiful-native-libraries/), the author uses this technique.

In the code below, at the end, it can be seen that the constructor is called explicitly:

```
#include <limits>

template <class T>
struct proxy_allocator {
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T *pointer;
    typedef const T *const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T &const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;

    template <class U>
    struct rebind {
        typedef proxy_allocator<U> other;
    };

    proxy_allocator() throw() {}
    proxy_allocator(const proxy_allocator &) throw() {}
    template <class U>
    proxy_allocator(const proxy_allocator<U> &) throw() {}
    ~proxy_allocator() throw() {}

    pointer address(reference x) const { return &x; }
    const_pointer address(const_reference x) const { return &x; }

    pointer allocate(size_type s, void const * = 0) {
        return s ? reinterpret_cast<pointer>(yl_malloc(s * sizeof(T))) : 0;
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type) {
        yl_free(p);
    }

    size_type max_size() const throw() {
        return std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / sizeof(T);
    }

    void construct(pointer p, const T& val) {
        new (reinterpret_cast<void *>(p)) T(val);
    }

    void destroy(pointer p) {
        p->~T();
    }

    bool operator==(const proxy_allocator<T> &other) const {
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const proxy_allocator<T> &other) const {
        return false;
    }
};
```

For some scenarios like this, it can be necessary to call constructors and destructors explicitly, but what does the standard say: is it undefined behavior, is it unspecified behavior, is it implementation defined behavior, or is it well defined?

Comment: You just have to make sure that each object is constructed once and destructed once

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, you cannot "call a constructor". Constructors have no names. They are invoked during the initialization of an object. One way to initialize an object is to use `new`. One syntax of `new` is placement new, which constructs an object at a given location.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes it is supported and well defined, it is safe.

```
new (reinterpret_cast<void *>(p)) T(val);
```

Is called the [*placement new syntax*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and is used to construct an object at a [specific memory location](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), the default behaviour; such as required in the allocator posted. If the placement new is overloaded for the specific type `T`, then it would be called instead of the global placement new.

The only way to destruct such a constructed object is to [explicitly call the destructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) `p->~T();`.

The use of the placement new and explicit destruction does require/allow that the code implemented controls the lifetime of the object - the compiler offers little assistance in this case; thus is it important that the objects are constructed in well aligned and sufficiently allocated locations. Their use is often found in allocators, such as in the OP, and the [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator).

Comment: Note: it is valid and allowed, certainly; however it should probably only appear in allocators/containers.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Are discriminating unions containers?  Optionals?  A max-fixed-size auto-storage `vector`-like?  (does not qualify as a container under the standard)  A SFO `function`-like?  It should probably only occur in low level, careful code, but only "allocators/containers" is pushing it.

Comment: @Yakk: I consider `optional`, `variant` and max-fixed-sized to be containers yes, since their only role is to contain other objects. No idea what a SFO is though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. -- a generic function-object, basically (it's container-ish enough)

Comment: @matt The C++ standard says what they mean by container.  I am not sure what does not qualify as a container, if you define container as "object that contains something".  SFO is small function optimization (like the more famous SSO): in general, when type erasimg down to value semantics, you'll probably wantna smallmobject optimization, which requires manual ctor/dtors.  Are all type erasers containers?

Comment: @Yakk: You can nitpick on the exact semantic of container (colloquial vs C++ vs...), I am not interested in this debate. You can argue that this rule of thumb is not complete, my reply will be that by definition rules of thumb are not complete :)

Comment: "If the placement new is overloaded for the specific type T, then it would be called instead of the global placement new.“ ... which is why decent allocators use `::new`.

Comment: @T.C. really?  You'd think that if someone overloads placement new taking a `void*` they *want* to replace placement new taking a void *, no?

Comment: @Yakk The allocator want to *construct an object at that exact spot*; the fact that it happens to use placement new to do it is an implementation detail, so why should we call someone's overload?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's completely safe. As a matter of fact, all **standard containers like `std::vector` use the technique** by default, because it is the only way to separate memory allocation from element construction.

More precisely, standard-container templates have an `Allocator` template argument which defaults to [`std::allocator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), and `std::allocator` uses placement new in its [`allocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate) member function.

This is, for example, what allows a `std::vector` to implement `push_back` such that memory allocation does not have to happen all the time, but instead some extra memory is allocated whenever the current capacity is no longer sufficient, preparing space for elements added with *future* `push_back`s.

This means that when you call `push_back` one hundred times in a loop, `std::vector` is actually clever enough not to allocate memory every time, which helps performance because reallocation and moving the existing container contents to a new memory location is costly.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    std::cout << "initial capacity: " << v.capacity() << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        v.push_back(0);

        std::cout << "capacity after " << (i + 1) << " push_back()s: "
            << v.capacity() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
initial capacity: 0
capacity after 1 push_back()s: 1
capacity after 2 push_back()s: 2
capacity after 3 push_back()s: 3
capacity after 4 push_back()s: 4
capacity after 5 push_back()s: 6
capacity after 6 push_back()s: 6
capacity after 7 push_back()s: 9
capacity after 8 push_back()s: 9
capacity after 9 push_back()s: 9
capacity after 10 push_back()s: 13
capacity after 11 push_back()s: 13
capacity after 12 push_back()s: 13
capacity after 13 push_back()s: 13
capacity after 14 push_back()s: 19
```

(...)

```
capacity after 94 push_back()s: 94
capacity after 95 push_back()s: 141
capacity after 96 push_back()s: 141
capacity after 97 push_back()s: 141
capacity after 98 push_back()s: 141
capacity after 99 push_back()s: 141
capacity after 100 push_back()s: 141
```

But of course, you **don't want to call a constructor for *potential future elements***. For `int` it would not matter, but we need a solution for every `T`, including types without default constructors. This is the power of placement new: allocate memory first, then place the elements in the allocated memory later, using a manual constructor call.

---

As a side note, all of this would be impossible with `new[]`. In fact, `new[]` is a pretty useless language feature.

---

P.S.: Just because standard containers internally use placement new, that does not mean that you should go wild with it in your own code. It *is* a low-level technique, and if you don't implement your own generic data structure because no standard container provides the functionality you need, you may never find any use for it at all.